# How to get a running CMD terminal by name/id in Windows and passing commands to it programmatically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cmd, terminal

There is an external CMD window running. The requirement is to get the handle/id of that CMD and pass it arguments at run-time from the C++ application.

Is there any direct way of doing it, ie running something in system("....") , a command which redirects to terminal addressed by handle or WinAPi needs to be used in this case.

Comment: Do you really mean `CMD` or do you mean `One of those white text on black background windows similar to CMD` ? Because not every console window has CMD.EXE running. And even in those where CMD.EXE is running, CMD.EXE may be a parent process who has delegated the standard I/O to a child process. Note that `system("foo")` is implemented by calling `CMD.EXE` and telling it to run `"foo"`.

Comment: Do you mean it is already running, or are you starting it yourself and asking how to communicate with it?

Comment: What if the process is busy? It sounds like you are attempting to solve your problem the wrong way

Comment: You cannot just inject commands into an external CMD process. Your app has to actually be running inside CMD's process.  You are probably better off simply locating the CMD window and then send keystrokes to it as needed. You can use `EnumProcesses()` to find the PID of the desired process, then use `EnumWindows()` and `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to find the window(s) belonging to that PID.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I see why I can't directly inject commands in CMD process. Going by other two options, I think it would be easier to just locate the CMD window and send keystrokes to it. (which would be commands to that process running under the CMD). Could you please elaborate a bit on it.

Comment: @MSalters  I got it. I was looking at the problem in the wrong way.